# Should I keep separate client codebases and databases for a software-as-a-service application?

Tags: architecture, ruby-on-rails

My question is about the architecture of my application. I have a Rails application where companies can administrate all things related to their clients. Companies would buy a subscription and their users can access the application online. Hopefully I will get multiple companies subscribing to my application/service. What should I do with my code and database?

1. Seperate app code base and database per company
2. One app code base but seperate database per company
3. One app code base and one database

The decision involves security (e.g. a user from company X should not see any data from company Y) performance (let's suppose it becomes successful, it should have a good performance) and scalability (again, if successful, it should have a good performance but also easy for me to handle all the companies, code changes, etc).

For the sake of maintainability, I tend to opt for the one code base, but for the database I really don't know. What do you think is the best option?

Comment: Why are you editing my question instead of answering? It's confusing now... I would go for the third option for the sake of simplicity, but I have doubts about security.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend sticking to a single codebase as best you can unless there are major customizations required by clients that you don't think will be reusable for others. Keeping multiple codebases in sync can turn into a maintenance nightmare, which will only escalate as your client base grows.

As for the database, it's usually best to keep the number to a minimum, but there are a few cases where it makes sense to partition your client data in separate databases:

1. You have strict (i.e. healthcare or financial industry) requirements on client data confidentiality.
2. Database performance becomes a problem.

Summary: option 3

Comment: I keep seeing this answer (about databases) around and it is always as unverified, unsupported and unexplained as this one. Why does it really "usually make sense" to keep databases to a minimum? Keep in mind that we are talking about databases and not databases servers.

Answer (score 3):

One previous employer started the `One app code base but separate database per company` model to support different clients, and the clients ended up wanting (and paying for) enough different features that they quickly ended up with `Seperate app code base and database per company`. So, based on past experiences, I think you'll follow the similar progression. Don't fork customer code bases until you have to, as it is a headache, but rather think about how your practices are and how you'd handle it, then when you are forced into that corner, you already have an idea how to do it.

I'd recommend staying away from `One app code base and one database` as you may find that customerX wants to take their data and go somewhere else (this might also be a subpoena or search warrant where you have to hand over data in a criminal case and you might not be able to cut out other customers' data). Many companies will prefer this route for risk management because this way a bug in your code will not expose data from other companies (like if you forgot a join, or  company ID in one where clause).

Answer (score 3):

i would go with option no. 1 because

- backup & restore per customer is possible out of the box
- no risk of exposing customer A`s data to customer B due a bug e.g. missing FK in query
- you can easily scale up or scale out (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/scaling-up-vs-scaling-out-hidden-costs.html), no load-balancer or replicated DB`s needed
- it is possible to have clients with different versions installed, which comes in handy when you roll out updates. you could/should update 1% of our customers first, if everything goes fine, update the next 10% and after that you update the rest.

Answer (score 2):

One app code base, one database schema,  but probably run the apps separately and have the dbs use the same schema actually be different db instances.

Don't design for it now, but you could imagine that if you need communication between these guys you could expose an api and have another service handle something like that, so a monolithic app is eh.  You also can potentially migrate the app to run on the clients server if they need that eventually, and you're overall reducing the complexity of the code in general. Basically what I'm saying is that I don't really see too much of the benefit of a monolith application that is a multi-company application as opposed to the companies application which you can run multiple of.  Of course this depends on the nature of your problem, but design small if you can.

Handle different features by basically just turning on and off different features via a key.  Hopefully this doesn't add too much complexity.  If you see lots of code doing if (permissionX) thats wrong.  You more so want functionality and features on the backend, and have a embedded view elements which you can bring into  a cheap throwaway view.  Think how wordpress does it- you should make plugins, and the system have all the functionality, but to say have the payment system button you have to pay for that.

Comment: Good answer. It's kind of amazing it took 5 years for someone to come along with the "right" answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go for the third option. Rails also makes it pretty simple to 'sandbox' the data related to a certain user so that others cannot see it.
From a performance point of view having one database to handle all the data can cause queries to be slower but there are numerous ways of improving this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would go with option #1 laced with lots of self-discipline until I had a very, very good understanding of the problem and what parts needed to be extensible on a per-client basis. Given you are starting off, you probably have some ideas as to what you want customizable, but your clients will want to customize things in ways you've never dream of. If you have a single application or a single codebase or both you'll then have to worry about how Client A's special needs impact Client B and vice versa. Having everyone in their own sandbox is a good way to be able to serve the customers, especially early-on when you really need to keep the few customer's you've got. Once the product matures a bit you will have a much better idea of where to build the extensibility points and how to make a single codebase that can serve most customers.

In terms of managing, it really isn't that hard with a bit of discipline. I'm not horribly familiar with ruby so I'm not sure what exact tools one would need to use, but with good scm practices and some automated deployment tools you can keep a handle on management while you are starting out. If you've got nightmares managing this codebase and all the separate apps then you've probably got a good problem to have. Alot better than figuring out how to customize a single monolithic codebase in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the third option for a few reasons.

One code base will make maintenance easier. You may also be able to leverage requests from clients into features other clients would benefit from. If you have a fragmented code base, this will be much more difficult to do and maintain. Not only that, but if you have separate code bases, as soon as you are in a rush, any discipline you had of applying fixes to each individual code base is likely to be forgotten or neglected in your haste.

As for the database, while having multiple databases per client sounds pretty good at this point in the project, as the product grows and matures, you may have one company outpacing the others in terms of usage. This will cause you to have to scale up each individual database separately. If you were using one database for all customers, you only need to scale when overall usage increases. You may run into an issue if one client is MUCH larger than the others, but that can be fixed by sharding your database when the time comes. That could give you the benefit of having a database per client, without the hassle of actually maintaining separate databases.

Another issue with having a single database per customer is -- what happens when you need to change the structure of the database for some reason? Would need to migrate each individual database? While Ruby has tools that help you update databases, I still view multiple migrations as an unnecessary risk.

Unless you have a need to have everything separate, keep everything as similar as possible. For security purposes, just make sure that all calls to the database include a reference to the client that is requesting the data. As long as that rule is enforced (and proper security measures are taken) you won't have to worry about companies seeing each others' data.

Comment: Although it makes it easy to charge more to that customer. "Your" database needs upgrade of $8000. Here's an invoice.

Comment: If you are growing to the point where you need to upgrade, I'd hope the cost of the upgrade is more than covered by the growth of the company. However, you are right, if you aren't charging enough for your services any sort of scaling is going to be near impossible.